# adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth not working with iOS 15 UIButton

Tags: swift, uibutton, ios15

I want to size the text on my button to automatically fit to the edges of the button.

This code was working pre-iOS15, now it doesn't.

```
testButton.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
testButton.titleLabel?.minimumScaleFactor = 0.1
```

**How can I automatically resize the text to fit the size of my button in iOS 15?**

---

This is playground code for testing. It includes everything I've tried, but still isn't working.

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

//building button
let testButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 300, height: 300))
testButton.setTitle("test", for: .normal)

//everything I've found in other answers that is supposed to work
var titleLabel = testButton.titleLabel!
titleLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 300)
titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
titleLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.1
titleLabel.numberOfLines = 1 //also tried 0 instead
titleLabel.lineBreakMode = .byClipping

//configuring button
testButton.configuration = UIButton.Configuration.filled()

//display the button
let containerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500))
containerView.backgroundColor = .white
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = containerView
containerView.addSubview(testButton)
```

Related questions I've already looked at and tried:

- [Best way to adjust font size with width and height of UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53725496/best-way-to-adjust-font-size-with-width-and-height-of-uilabel)
- [Swift - Adjusting fontSize to fit the width of the layout (programmatically)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28734000/swift-adjusting-fontsize-to-fit-the-width-of-the-layout-programmatically)
- [How to get .adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth to function properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28996320/how-to-get-adjustsfontsizetofitwidth-to-function-properly)
- [How to set font size to fill UILabel height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8812192/how-to-set-font-size-to-fill-uilabel-height)
- [Auto change the font size to fit the button in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38062091/auto-change-the-font-size-to-fit-the-button-in-swift)
- [UIButton auto-adjust Button font size Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32694519/uibutton-auto-adjust-button-font-size-swift)

Comment: Report it to Apple.

Answer (score 0):

I found out it could be caused by `testButton.configuration = UIButton.Configuration.filled()`, but I don't know why.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31875485)